# Adding advertisement to android application using php file

Tags: php, android, ads

I have created android application for chatting like whatsapp. But I want to show advertisement at the specified location and content of the advertise like title,link,image will be fetch using php file.so how i can do this.Please help me to if you know.I have searched a lot but no solution found.

Comment: i'm using https://www.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/

but if you want to use your own advertise from a webpage use a webview the loads your page.

Comment: I have seen about admob but I want to post my own advertisement to my application

Comment: Add a webview that loads your page php page and then when is pressed you can open the link on other app depending on the link.

Comment: But I dont want to use webview. I just want to use Linearlayout with TextView,ImageView and load that textview and imageView from php file in background.

Comment: Sorry can you post what is exactly your php file showing ? is it some rest service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that problem by creating popup window...I have created small strip like layout that contain TextView,ImgaView,Button and so on.
popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/popup"
android:color="#66FF0000" 

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Ad Description" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="www.nspiresfot.com" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Ad Title" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_openAd"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/send" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.popwindow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Point p;
 PopupWindow popup;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Button btn_show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);
   p = new Point();
   p.x = 0;
   p.y =60;
   //Open popup window
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        if (p != null)
          showPopup(MainActivity.this, p);
    }
}, 900L);
}


// The method that displays the popup.
private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
   int popupWidth = 240;
   int popupHeight = 50;

   //Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);
   layout.getBackground().setAlpha(90);
   //Creating the PopupWindow
   popup = new PopupWindow(context);
   popup.setContentView(layout);
   popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popup.setHeight(popupHeight);

   popup.setFocusable(false);

   // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
   int OFFSET_X = 0;
   int OFFSET_Y = 0;

   // Clear the default translucent background
   popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
   popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
  // popup.showAtLocation(layout,  Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, getRequestedOrientation(), getRequestedOrientation());
   // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
   Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       popup.dismiss();
     }
   });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
     popup.dismiss();
}

}
```

and then I have used php file to load all textview and imageview.